# Castle Windsong in a book that sings when the wind blows

Tags: story-identification, books

There was this cool castle in the book, I think it was like a giant harmonica when the wind blew it sang and they called it Castle Windsong.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly [*The Harp of Imach Thyssel*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/169867.The_Harp_of_Imach_Thyssel) (1985) by Patricia C. Wrede, the third book in the [Lyra series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41408-lyra). There is a castle called Windsong there that makes music.

> The harp had been lost for centuries until Emereck the minstrel stumbled across it in an abandoned castle. Emereck wished it had never been found at all - for all magic has its price. Nonetheless, it was one of the greatest treasures in the world of Lyra - for its music could make a dying man whole or a whole city die, according to the songs of old.

Comment: Now that you mention Lyra I remember Lyre being used in the book as a synomym for a type of instrument either a lute or harp possibly.

Comment: The old Star Wars Jedi Academy Trilogy introduced the planet Vortex Cathedral of Winds. From Wookipedia: “The center of the Vor's society was the Cathedral of Winds, a building that resonated with tones as the planet's strong winds struck it.” It was key parts of 2nd & 3rd books regarding Ackbar plot.